# Why is this conditional different?

Tags: conditional-constructions

In this conditional "If Kennedy had survived, the US would be very different now" the if clause uses a past perfect form and the main clause a simple past one. Why is that? This sentence is an example of third conditional and so the main clause should be written as "the US would have been very different now". So, why is it written in past simple? Thanks.

Comment: It is apparently a mistake. Also "survuve" is a mistake, the past participle is "survived". What is the source  of your quote?

Comment: The main clause isn't "simple past" - it's a *conditional* involving the auxiliary ***would** [be]* (where ***be*** is actually an infinitive). In other contexts it would be quite possible to use the ***perfect*** form there - for example, *If he **had shot** her she **would have died / have been dead***. But because your main clause includes ***now***, we wouldn't usually explicitly cast it into the past with a perfect form. It's still *theoretically* possible, but idiomatically not likely.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If Kennedy **had survived**, the US **would be very different now.**

**If that sentence is allowable**, so too is:

If I **had gone**, I **would see** him. [That one is not grammatical.]

For me, "had survived" is a past tense, therefore, one needs to write:

**If Kennedy had survived, the US would have been very different now**. [Of course, it isn't very different, is it? We in the US ended up with the orange man].

**Does one see** the following?

If Kennedy had survived, the US  would be different now.

**Yes, one sees it**, but personally, I would change it for the reason I showed above.

There are cases of mixed conditionals, etc. This is not one of them.

**You can't accept one rule for one group of sentences, and then not for all the ones with the same pattern. There needs to be coherence.**

**The past conditional is pretty clear and requires a past conditional tense in the main clause. It refers to a past situation that never actually happened.**

What might/could/should have been the outcome, if Kennedy had survived?
That would be a mixed conditional, in simple terms.

*There are times that if does not mean if.*

Here it does.

When does the little word if not mean if? In utterances like this>

If he went, it was because he wanted too.

There, if means: assuming that he went, in the event that he went.

That way, there can be no doubt. That said, when there is a past with IF, as with this sentence, it is unreal. Therefore, the verb in the main clause must be: would have + PP. Or past conditional tense.

Comment: I downvoted this because it's just wrong and confusing, and, honestly, I don't like your formatting (and I know you won't let me edit this). I don't know what dialect you're a speaker of, but in Standard English, *If I had gone, I would see him* is grammatical. For example, you're now in Canada, and he's in the U.S. If you had gone to the U.S. when the opportunity presented itself, you would see him now. Does that not make sense to you?

Comment: @userr2684291  ***If I had gone, I would have seen him*** is Standard English. Your example of Canada and the U.S. would also be in Standard English form: If I went [now], I would see him. "If I had gone, I would see him" is not Standard English at all. You might want to revisit your grammar.....just saying. And these examples are the same across all varieties of English.

Comment: "If I had gone" means you did not go and is a past tense, therefore, the main clause requires past tense: would have seen him.

Comment: You are mistaken. I honestly implore you to read [this](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv344.shtml), [this](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/quick-grammar/conditionals-2), or [this](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/mixed-conditional/) to remind yourself of Standard English. In high school we called these "mixed conditionals", so you can google that as well.

Comment: The BBC says: ***These combinations are not all that frequent**, but the most common combination is when we have a type 3 conditional in the if-clause (if + past perfect) followed by a type 2 conditional (would + infinitive) in the main clause." It also most definitely does not say that it's "Standard English".

Comment: Personally, in a formal article, I would not use a mixed conditional.

Comment: That's only because they're literally not as frequently used; i.e., you don't use it that often. They would probably also say that you don't use *will have done it* as frequently as you do the simple *will* + infinitive construction. They don't have to qualify every statement there with *this is Standard English*. Why would they teach non-Standard English? If the construction were informal or colloquial, or perhaps borderline Standard English, they would've indicated so. But it isn't.

Comment: In any event, "If I had gone, I would see him" is not grammatical.

Comment: Have you read the articles I linked you to? They present you with Standard English constructions. That sentence is grammatical. The "mixed conditional" constructions are used in both formal and informal Englishes.

Comment: How about this little paragraph: *This country provides me with no opportunities at all: I am as poor now as I was 30 years ago. If I **had gone** to America **then**, I **would not have been able** to afford a house **then**, but I **would be able** to afford it **now**.* I know it's a silly example, but notice the tenses. It's possible to connect the past and the present like this in Standard English. And this isn't something arcane either; this same construction exists in my first language as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74319/discussion-between-lambie-and-userr2684291).

Answer (score 4):

First, correct the participle in your sentence:

> If Kennedy had **survived**, the US would be very different now.

Next, ignore the category "third conditional"—in fact, discard everything you've learned about the "n conditionals". This system is a pedagogic device intended to introduce learners to conditional constructions, not a linguistic description of conditional constructions. The system confuses forms and meanings, and is irrelevant here.

*Would be* is not a "simple past"—it is a past-form modal employed to designate an "unreal" present eventuality. *Had survived* is a past-perfect form employed to designate an "unreal" past eventuality.

The sentence thus describes the **hypothetical** present-day consequence of an imaginary past event which is known to be contrary to fact.

Comment: It seems to me (1) *If he hadn't died in the war, I **would be** married now* and (2) *... I **would have been** married now* are both "valid". But to me the perfect form implies more "distance" from the here and now, which arguably makes it more "wistful". I find it interesting to contemplate that nuance of "more hypothetical / unreal" specifically in the context of switching the subject from ***I*** to ***we*** in my example.

Comment: '...discard everything you've learned about the "n conditionals". This system is a pedagogic device intended to introduce learners to conditional constructions, not a linguistic description of conditional constructions.' ?? This is English language learner's SE, why should learners discard pedagogic devices? And isn't "would have been" the preferred construction here?

Comment: @laugh I invite folks to discard the n-conditional system when they've advanced beyond the point where the system is helpful and informative. And No, *would have been different* is not preferred here: it designates a different state in the past, not in the present.

Comment: I find that in forums like these, leaning heavily on grammatical lingo can be very confusing to learners. When I'm learning a language, I appreciate really simple explanations with concrete examples. Frankly, I would say: If Kennedy had survived, the US would have been different. In a formal written context. That said, people say "would be" all the time. You can discard everything, except certain bits that are fine....

Comment: Good point about the present state (I misread the question) but with that in mind, isn't it better to use "If Kennedy survived, the US would be..." (which is pedagogically the second conditional)?

Comment: Do you accept: If I had gone, I would see him? Because you can't accept the OP's sentence and reject that. If they had played, they would be here? Personally, I would not.

Comment: @laugh : No; Either **a)** This is a present inference with "now" as the present--which would imply, falsely, that whether Kennedy survived is at the present time unknown, or **b)** This is a narrative in which "now" refers to the brief time when whether Kennedy survived was still unknown.

Comment: If you accept the sentence, you have to accept all similar ones, which is frankly, absurd.

Comment: @Lambie OP's sentence speaks to a present consequence of a past eventuality. "I didn't go his wedding, and he was offended. That's why he isn't to be seen here at my wedding. If I **had gone**, I **would see** him now."

Comment: ***If had gone to his wedding, I would've seen him here today at mine but I haven't. He hasn't shown up here.***. I don't accept your analysis. Sorry. ***Because then*** all the other instances would have to work and they clearly do not. The ***would have seen him*** is the outcome....he ain't there.

Comment: @Lambie If I hadn't taken my meds this morning I would be frothing with frustration right now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73676/discussion-between-lambie-and-stoneyb).